# Go-vet complains about unsafeptr when CMatrix is converted to slice

Tags: opencv, go

I'm using openCV with Go and have this function:

```
func ConvertMatToSlice(c_Mat *CMatrix) []float32 {
    c_output := C.Convert(c_Mat.CType)
    h := &reflect.SliceHeader{
        Data: uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(c_output.val)),
        Len:  int(c_output.length),
        Cap:  int(c_output.length),
    }
    return *(*[]float32)(unsafe.Pointer(h))
}
```

When I run `go vet ./...` it gives me:

```
opencv_wrapper.go:31:7: unsafeptr: possible misuse of reflect.SliceHeader (govet)
    h := &reflect.SliceHeader{
         ^
```

Is there any other way to get the slice because I'm sure go-vet has its reasons to complain about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Go Issue #40701](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40701). A safer alternative would be the following:

```
func ConvertMatToSlice(c_Mat *CMatrix) []float32 {
    c_output := C.Convert(c_Mat.CType)
    result := make([]float32, c_output.length)
    sh := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&result))
    sh.Data = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(c_output.val))
    return result
}
```

I've made a [test program](https://play.golang.org/p/RYUQm2jV_Bp) mocking the behaviour of your code without using cgo. So let's place it in a directory and do some escape analysis with `go build -gcflags "-m -m"`.

What we're interested is making sure that the slice (slice header) we return is allocated on the heap, and that so is the pointer which it points to in the `Data` field. As we can see from the escape analysis, `b` escapes and so does the slice allocation:

```
./main.go:10:6: b escapes to heap:
./main.go:10:6:   flow: {storage for &Output literal} = &b:
./main.go:10:6:     from &b (address-of) at ./main.go:17:38
[...]
./main.go:25:16: make([]float32, c_output.length) escapes to heap:
./main.go:25:16:   flow: {heap} = &{storage for make([]float32, c_output.length)}:
./main.go:25:16:     from make([]float32, c_output.length) (non-constant size) at ./main.go:25:16
```

In your case, you'll have to make sure yourself from the C code that the pointer is allocated on the heap.

In general, the rule that can be taken from the discussion on the Go issue I've referenced is to never create SliceHeaders yourself. They might work but they can and will lead to memory corruption, creating difficult and hard-to-debug situations in your code. If you do need to get access to a slice yourself, do so either by using `make` or by using [`reflect.MakeSlice`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#MakeSlice) which are guaranteed to work and will cooperate with the GC properly, and then make the necessary changes to the slice header.

Comment: I have moved to Go 1.21 which now deprecates the use of `reflect.SliceHeader` I will try to work out a replacement for the above code that go is happy with.

Answer (score 0):

With Go 1.21 the use of refelect.SliceHeader header has been depricated.  Alternative code to do similar now looks like

```golang
func ConvertMatToSlice(c_Mat *CMatrix) []float32 {
    c_output := C.Convert(c_Mat.CType)
    sh := unsafe.Slice(c_output.val, c_output.length)
    return *(*[]float32)(unsafe.Pointer(&sh))
}
```

Everything said in the earlier answer still stands.